# HTML audio player not working in Android app

Tags: android, html, html5-audio

I am working in Android app using html, jQuery, phonegap.

Here I am trying to put HTML5 audio player.That is not working with the local app song path in app folder but when I put an online song path that works fine(ex: http://example.com/audio1.mp3)

**In Below my coding with path from online song url which is working:**

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="http://example.com/audio1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

**In Below my coding with local app path which is not  working:**

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="/android_asset/www/media/demo.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

I was trying to resolve this but no success.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case the `src` is wrong. 
It should be `file:///android_asset/www/media/demo.mp3`.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. But not working with this path file:///android_asset/www/media/demo.mp3

Comment: The URL syntax for local assets is `file:///android_asset/...`  
Are you absolutely sure the relative path, represented by `...`, is correct?

Comment: the relative path is assets/www/media/demo.mp3 but i have worked using  phone gap native media player, there is set path "/android_asset/..." so i put that path, I am also tring with "assets/www/media/demo.mp3" those are not working...